# React: Reactstrap modal crashes app when closing

Tags: reactjs

My modal causes a crash whenever I close it. The modal contains picture details and is displaying them.

The error message I am getting is:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Although the above `prop` worked fine while the modal was open. A thing I noted is that whenever the modal contains only the below paragraph with the id, it works fine and closes without any issues.

```
<p>{modalContent.id}</p>
```

Where the `FavoritesModal` gets its `props`

```
const FavoritesSidebar = () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null)

  const favoriteList = useSelector((state) => state.favoriteList)


  const toggleModal = (arg) => {
    setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
    setModalContent(arg)
  }

  return (
    <Container className="favorites-sidebar">
      {/* {modalContent ? <p>yes</p> : <p>no</p>} */}
      {favoriteList.length > 0 ? <h4>Your favorited pictures</h4> : null}

      {favoriteList.length > 0 &&
        favoriteList.map((item) => (
          <Row key={item.id} className="favorite-item">
            <Col onClick={() => toggleModal(item)}>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}

      {modalContent ? (
        <FavoritesModal
          modalOpen={modalOpen}
          modalContent={modalContent}
          toggleModal={toggleModal}
        />
      ) : null}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default FavoritesSidebar
```

`FavoritesModal`

```
const FavoritesModal = (props) => {
  const { modalOpen, modalContent, toggleModal } = props

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  if (modalContent)
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalOpen}
        toggle={toggleModal}
        centered
        fullscreen=""
        size="xl"
      >
        <ModalHeader>
          <p>
            {modalContent.description !== null
              ? `${modalContent.description} by ${modalContent.user.name}`
              : `Taken by: ${modalContent.user.name}`}
          </p>
          <p>{modalContent.id}</p>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <img src={modalContent.urls.regular} alt={modalContent.description} />
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button
            color="danger"
            onClick={() => dispatch(removeFromFavorites(modalContent.id))}
          >
            Remove from favorites
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    )
  else return null
}

export default FavoritesModal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the toggleModal functioned solved the issue

```
 const toggleModal = (arg) => {
    if (modalOpen) {
      setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
      setModalContent(null)
    } else {
      setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
      setModalContent(arg)
    }
  }
```